# Surface charge on dielectric interface

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

What I have in mind is a system that consists of a capacitor filled with two dielectric materials, one of them with dielectric constant $\kappa_1$ and the other with $\kappa_2$. The capacitor is connected to a battery of voltage, say $V$. As the dielectric constant of the plates are different, I would expect a surface density at the interface of the two dielectric materials. I want to calculate this surface charge density.

---

I have the following figure in my mind but with two different slabs of dielectrics (area and length are the same).

[image]

Now let the $Q_0$ be the charge on the plates when the dielectric material was absent. Now when the dielectric slabs are fitted, then the charge on the upper plate would be $Q_1=\kappa_1 Q_0$ and on the lower plate $Q_2=\kappa_2 Q_0$ but this doesn't seem right to me! as I have never seen a capacitor with different charges on plates. That means charges must redistribute themselves to make it equal. But that would mean $Q_1=Q_2 \Rightarrow \kappa_1=\kappa_2$ but that is incorrect.

Now if I take some equivalent constant for the two plates, say $\kappa$ and say that the charges on the upper and lower plate is $Q=\kappa Q_0$. Then the charge on the upper dielectric plate would be $Q'_1=(1-\kappa )Q_0$ and on the lower part of the second dielectric would be $Q'_2=Q'_1$. But that's the same as one plate case and I don't know what to do.

---

Can someone point out the flaw in my thinking and give me a right approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of the field D displacement.
Since $\nabla \cdot D = \rho_{free}$ , using gauss law with a cilinder passing trough the planes, you get that $D$ inside the capacitor is uniform (Similar argument to the classic capacitor).
Now you have that for linear dielectrics $D=\epsilon E$

to get $D$ from the $\Delta V$ you compute the integral

$\Delta V= -\int_{a}^{c} E \,dx =-\int_{a}^{b} E \,dx -\int_{b}^{c} E \,dx=$
$=-\int_{a}^{b} \frac{D}{\epsilon_1} \,dx-\int_{b}^{c} \frac{D}{\epsilon_2} \,dx$

where a, b, c are points on the tree surfaces (b being the middle one)
so (since D is uniform)

$D=\frac{\Delta V}{\frac{(b-a)}{\epsilon_1}+\frac{(c-b)}{\epsilon_2}}$

I did not put too much attention on signs but you get my point.

Now from $D$ trough $D=\epsilon E$ you get the two fields in the to regions, and their difference is $\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ (Gauss law), so you can evaluate $\rho$ between the two dielectrics.

Comment: And I hate when someone doesn't tell me my fault nor tell me How to proceed the way I did and give another way to solve it. In the present case, I m not interested in doing it with the displacement field.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi Well, i get your point, but since I spent 15 min of my time answering to you, you could be more polite.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi anyway, when you say that there shoud hold $Q_1=k_1Q_0$, think about how this result is obtained and see that it just hold for a capacitor filled with ONE and only one dielectric. So that is a wrong approach to the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and sorry If I were harsh. How do I proceed without introducing the displacement field? How the picture would look like for two dielectrics? Like the one shown.